# How to scrape value from <script> tag with BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to write parser for site, and i face this problem, `BS4` cant get text from  tag, instead he prints empty strings. I need to get russian text from this(ofc i have a lot of this script blocks, for example 91):

```
<tr>
  <td class="egeno"><span>1</span></td>
  <td class="topicview">
  <script>
  document.write( '(№&nbsp;4840) ' ); 
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('На рисунке схема дорог Н-ского района изображена в виде графа, в таблице содержатся сведения о длине этих дорог в километрах. <br/><img src="4840.gif">Так как таблицу и схему рисовали независимо друг от друга, нумерация населённых пунктов в таблице никак не связана с буквенными обозначениями на графе. Известно, что длина дороги ЗЕ равна 15 км. Определите длину дороги БГ. В ответе запишите целое число – длину дороги в километрах.') );
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="egeno"><span>1</span></td>
  <td class="topicview">
  <script>
  document.write( '(№&nbsp;4839) ' ); 
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('На рисунке схема дорог Н-ского района изображена в виде графа, в таблице содержатся сведения о длине этих дорог в километрах. <br/><img src="4839.gif">Так как таблицу и схему рисовали независимо друг от друга, нумерация населённых пунктов в таблице никак не связана с буквенными обозначениями на графе. Известно, что длина дороги ЗЕ равна 15 км. Определите длину дороги БГ. В ответе запишите целое число – длину дороги в километрах.') );
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

I add some information in my bd as well, but i think it doesn't matter.
I commented some strings because i needed.
This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, sqlite3
import re
import json
i = 1


task1_hrefs = soup.find_all(class_='topicview')
print(task1_hrefs)

for task in task1_hrefs:
    task_text = task.text
    print(i, "", f"{task_text}")
```

All in all, i need to have in task_text all tasks in turn because i will add all of tasks in bd

html code with other class:

```
<table class="vartopic">
<tr>
  <td class="egeno"><span>1</span></td>
  <td class="topicview">
  <script>
  document.write( '(№&nbsp;5989) ' ); 
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('(А. Богданов) На рисунке справа схема дорог Н-ского района изображена в виде графа, в таблице содержатся сведения о длинах этих дорог (в километрах). Так как таблицу и схему рисовали независимо друг от друга, то нумерация населённых пунктов в таблице никак не связана с буквенными обозначениями на графе. В таблице в левом столбце указаны номера пунктов, откуда совершается движение, в первой строке – куда. <br/><img src="5989.gif">Определите сумму длин дорог CB, CG и CE. Передвигаться можно только по указанным дорогам.') );
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td class="answer">
  <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="p5989" 
     onclick="showDiv('5989')">Показать ответ</a></p>
  <div class="hidedata" id="5989"><script>
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('41') );
  </script></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="egeno"><span>1</span></td>
  <td class="topicview">
  <script>
  document.write( '(№&nbsp;5893) ' ); 
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('(Е. Джобс) На рисунке справа схема дорог Н-ского района изображена в виде графа, в таблице содержатся сведения о длинах этих дорог (в километрах). Так как таблицу и схему рисовали независимо друг от друга, то нумерация населённых пунктов в таблице никак не связана с буквенными обозначениями на графе. В таблице в левом столбце указаны номера пунктов, откуда совершается движение, в первой строке – куда. <br/><img src="5893.gif">Определите длину кратчайшего маршрута между пунктами Г и З. Передвигаться можно только по указанным дорогам.') );
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to get your goal:

```
re.search(r"document.write\( changeImageFilePath\((.*?)\)", e.script.text).group(1)
```

##### Example

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr>
  <td class="egeno"><span>1</span></td>
  <td class="topicview">
  <script>
  document.write( '(№&nbsp;4840) ' ); 
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('На рисунке схема дорог Н-ского района изображена в виде графа, в таблице содержатся сведения о длине этих дорог в километрах. <br/><img src="4840.gif">Так как таблицу и схему рисовали независимо друг от друга, нумерация населённых пунктов в таблице никак не связана с буквенными обозначениями на графе. Известно, что длина дороги ЗЕ равна 15 км. Определите длину дороги БГ. В ответе запишите целое число – длину дороги в километрах.') );
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="egeno"><span>1</span></td>
  <td class="topicview">
  <script>
  document.write( '(№&nbsp;4839) ' ); 
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('На рисунке схема дорог Н-ского района изображена в виде графа, в таблице содержатся сведения о длине этих дорог в километрах. <br/><img src="4839.gif">Так как таблицу и схему рисовали независимо друг от друга, нумерация населённых пунктов в таблице никак не связана с буквенными обозначениями на графе. Известно, что длина дороги ЗЕ равна 15 км. Определите длину дороги БГ. В ответе запишите целое число – длину дороги в километрах.') );
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 

for e in soup.select('tr'):
    print(re.search(r"document.write\( changeImageFilePath\((.*?)\)", e.script.text).group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the text is wrapped in a `script` tag, get it from there:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<tr>
  <td class="egeno"><span>1</span></td>
  <td class="topicview">
  <script>
  document.write( '(№&nbsp;4840) ' ); 
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('На рисунке схема дорог Н-ского района изображена в виде графа, в таблице содержатся сведения о длине этих дорог в километрах. <br/><img src="4840.gif">Так как таблицу и схему рисовали независимо друг от друга, нумерация населённых пунктов в таблице никак не связана с буквенными обозначениями на графе. Известно, что длина дороги ЗЕ равна 15 км. Определите длину дороги БГ. В ответе запишите целое число – длину дороги в километрах.') );
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="egeno"><span>1</span></td>
  <td class="topicview">
  <script>
  document.write( '(№&nbsp;4839) ' ); 
  document.write( changeImageFilePath('На рисунке схема дорог Н-ского района изображена в виде графа, в таблице содержатся сведения о длине этих дорог в километрах. <br/><img src="4839.gif">Так как таблицу и схему рисовали независимо друг от друга, нумерация населённых пунктов в таблице никак не связана с буквенными обозначениями на графе. Известно, что длина дороги ЗЕ равна 15 км. Определите длину дороги БГ. В ответе запишите целое число – длину дороги в километрах.') );
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    if 'changeImageFilePath' in script.text:
        text = script.text.split('changeImageFilePath(\'')[1].split('\')')[0]
        text = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
        print(text.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its was really work on this piece of html code, but somehow on full html code i have this error:text = script.text.split('changeImageFilePath(\'')[1].split('\')')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: i will try to add full html code, mb this is matter?

Comment: Im sorry that im so stupid

Comment: there are some other scripts(that is not for tasks), mb it causes the error

Comment: You can add additional filtering criteria to `if 'changeImageFilePath' in script.text:` to make sure you only get the scripts you need. Or wrap it in try-except

Comment: Thanks a lot) i already figured it out myself) Should I do something with my question? mb delete it?